# Validating API response in Karate framework

Tags: karate

I want help for validating API response using karate framework.
I have API’s which are “Independent” on each other.
I have POST method along with request parameters. when I hit that particular API got the response with different parameters (no single match from request parameter and response parameter).

Now I want to validate response parameter value.

example : request: “method” post

school name: “abcd”
register date : “1:10:2010″

Response:
Principle name : ” pqrs”
Principle Email id “pqrs@gmail.com

now I want to validate that “principle name ” should not be null

I have implemented like this but it it doesn’t work

```
Feature: School info

 Background:
  * url baseUrl

 Scenario: check Principles info

  Given path ‘School info’
  And request {school name: “abcd” ,register date : “1:10:2010”}
  When method post
  Then status 200
  And match response.response contains {“type”: “Success”,”code”:20000}
  And match response.principle list[*] { “Principle name”: “#notnull”}
```

whenever I run this file it always passes the API `wvwnt` if the Principle name filed is null.
It just checks the success message (`And match response.response contains {“type”: “Success”, ”code”:20000}`) and pass the API

Answer (score 1):

your code for validating principlelist doesn't have proper assertions.

`match each` will be more convenient for validating json array with a schema

```
* match each response.principlelist contains {"Principal name" : "#notnull"}
```